# Android opengl modify vertex array after draw call

Tags: java, android, arrays, opengl-es, vertex

In opengl, is it bad practice or not recommended to modify the vertex array after I have drawn it?

Comment: You should use double buffering to avoid performance issues with vertex buffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **not** bad practice if you modify the vertex array when you draw it as ordinary vertex array.

**It's** bad practice to modify the vertex array if you use vertex buffer objects in your draw method. That's because you have to reupload it to your VRAM once it is edited.

Comment: So, in android development it would be considered bad since I am forced to use VBO.

Comment: @semajhan: Yes, because you need to reupload your VBO:s during play time/rendering time and that would decrease performance. Stick with `translate`/`scale` when possible. You can upload a lot of different Vertex Array's when your renderer is being initialized and then just switch the pointer to another already uploaded Vertex Array.

Comment: I was trying to modify the Vertex Array to implement scrolling of a 2D map by shifting within the Vertex Array. Thanks for the info.