# OpenGL ES 2.0, best practice to do transformations

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm writing "for fun" my own graphic engine for Android with OpenGL ES 2.0.

After managing a whole scene with multiple objects mesh, I'm trying to implement Shadow Volumes.

The logic is (simplified) : first, I create an object (with vertices, faces, edges and all data) from a binary file. After that, I create a Vertex Buffer and draw elements.

Until now, I used transformation (scale, translation, rotation) with OpenGL functions on the model matrix (glRotate, etc..).

But for using Shadow Volume, I must, every time an object or light is transformed, calculate which faces are in front of light and the silhouette. So I use a loop on my vertex array.

My question is : Where to do transformations ? Do I have to transform the vertex array on every change and reload it in the Vertex Buffer ?

According to this, it's a bad thing : [Android opengl modify vertex array after draw call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703550/android-opengl-modify-vertex-array-after-draw-call)

So, what is the best practice ?

Sorry for my poor english and thank you in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only roughly remember shadow volumes, but if I remember correctly then you first determine face in front of the light, the border of these faces is the silhouette which spans the volume, right?

So you want to do something like this for every vertex normal n and the lightvector l:

front = (l dot M * n) < 0.0 ? true : false

where M is the inverse transposed of your vertex transformation matrix.

Instead of multiplying each normal with n, can't you compute a proper transformation for the lightvector...ie a matrix Ml with:

(Ml * l dot n) = (l dot M * n)

That would be my idea.

Comment: Tank you. Yes, each faces in front of light that have one (or more) neighbours in back of light, is part of the silhouette. I know how to deal with Shadow Volume. My question is about where to do transformations on my object (scale, translate, rotate) ? As I must recalculate faces for Shadow Volume on each transformation (object or light). If I transform my vertex array, I need to reload it in the Vertex Buffer every time, it will decrease performance...

Comment: i'm still not sure if I understood your problem...
your object or the light was transformed with an affine transformation and thus you have to recalculate the shadow volume, right?
...for the volume you need to compute the current silhouette and for that you have to determine face in front of the light, right?
...and the problem is that you don't want to transform each vertex if this happens since its quite costly, right?

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault and my poor english.. No, I speak about Shadow Volume only for explaining why I need to do transformations on the vertex array. Now (before implementing shadow), I load a Vertex Buffer from the vertex array and I translage, scale, rotate by matrix on the model matrix with OpenGL functions (gltranslate, glrotate...). But like I need to transform my vertex array first (for shadow), how to deal with the Vertex Buffer ? Need I to reload it every time ? It's not a good thing for performance.. Do you understand ?

Comment: what i suggested was that instead of transforming your mesh (where you would have to apply a matrix for every vertex), you can find transformation for the light source so that the relative position between lightsource and your mesh is the same like when you transform the mesh, but you would only have to apply the matrix once (for the light).

Comment: this way you get the faces which are in front of the light without matrix multiplication for each vertex. and for the found faces you can then compute the border/silhouete and transform the silhouette only with the initial mesh-transformation to get a result in the correct coordinate-frame. a bit complicated. i hope you get the idea.

Comment: basically you should not touch the vertex buffer where possible.

Comment: Ho ! The light comes to me !! Tank you very much, I get the idea !! Very elegant solution ;) Sorry, I'm new here, I don't have enough reputation for voting for you.. Again, thank you for your time !